# How to implement count down timer in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer, countdown

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">2:00:00</asp:Label>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Default.aspx.vb**

```
Dim timer, timer_arr() As String
timer = Label1.Text
timer_arr = timer.Split(":")
Dim seconds = Integer.Parse(timer_arr(2))
Dim minutes = Integer.Parse(timer_arr(1))
Dim hours = Integer.Parse(timer_arr(0))
If seconds = 0 And minutes = 0 And hours = 0 Then
    Timer1.Enabled = False
Else
    seconds = seconds - 1
End If
If (seconds < 0) Then
    seconds = 59
    minutes = minutes - 1
End If
If minutes < 0 Then
    minutes = 59
    hours = hours - 1
End If

Label1.Text = hours & ":" & minutes & ":" & seconds
```

The above code showing the expected result, i mean, i need the count down timer, which will display the countdown timer to the client like `2:45:34`. But the problem is the value of seconds is decreasing by twice. i mean after `2:45:34` in the next second instead of displaying `2:45:33`, it displaying `2:45:32` and so on. I'm very confused, from my point of view, everything is all right. Need help !!

**UPDATED**

I believe, client side scripting i.e. javascript will be the another option, but i need the timer for online exam system, which means timer should continue ticking whenever client send the request to the server. But, if i will use javascript then timer value will interrupted and will show unexpected value i.e. may be initialized again, and other cause. So, i believe server side scripting will be the best. If anyone have other suggestion, then i will appreciate. !!

Comment: Why in the world do you need to ask the server for the time? Setup the page with the initial countdown value and run it purely client side. Your probably seeing the 1 second skip from the ajax latency.

Comment: so, you mean, i will have to implement the same using javascript

Comment: i need the timer for online exam. So, as per your suggestion, server side timer won't be good option, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, its too late to share answer of this question, Since, i found this solution and i felt, other can get the benefit of my solution.

this is what i done...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="questionText" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:HiddenField ID="txt_timer" Value="00:30:00" runat="server" />
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1830" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have used hiddenfield, which keep update the timer and now, i'm using `<div>` on which i'm displaying the counter

```
<div id="counter" style="position: absolute; top: 165px; left: 850px;"></div>
```

now i added my javascript and css code to my file for better look of count-down timer

**timer.js**

```
<script src="../ajax/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('#counter').countdown({
          image: '../images/digits.png',
          startTime: document.getElementById('<%= txt_timer.ClientID %>').value,
        //  timerEnd: function(){ //alert('end!'); },        
           });           
      });
    </script>
```

**timer.CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .cntSeparator
    {
        font-size: 55px;
        margin: 5px 2px;
        color: #000;
    }
</style>
```

**You can see demo of countdown timer [here](http://jquery-countdown.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the TimeSpan object ?

```
Dim ts as new TimeSpan(Integer.Parse(timer_arr(0)),Integer.Parse(timer_arr(1)),Integer.Parse(timer_arr(2)))
dim oneSecond as new TimeSpan(0,0,1) ' hours,min,sec
ts=ts.Subtract(oneSecond)
Label1.Text=ts.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
```

i've not tested it but should be great

Comment: 'Substract' is not a member of 'System.TimeSpan'

Comment: Oh, it's Subtract and not Substract ! Sorry ! [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.subtract.aspx) @coders

Comment: @coders also, to avoid problems, i would keep the TimeSpan a in a server variable, this way, the label only shows time left and is not used to recover it ...

Answer (score 0):

This could(and probably should) be done using javascript but if you need to use server side code then I would first suggest that you decrease the interval to half a second instead of a full second to accomadate for some of the latency between the server and the client machine. Secondly I would make sure that the only portion of the page being sent back and forth is the timer label itself to make the packets being passed around as small as possible. The code itself doesn't look like it will take more than a few milliseconds so I think the reason you are seeing the 2 second jump is mainly because of the timer interval.

As its been said, you could parse the string out into a datetime variable and then use the addseconds function to subtract a second(by passing in -1) instead of spliting the string and manually manipulating each field. I am more familiar with datetime objects than timespans but its really personal preference. if you use a datetime object you will need to call the `.toshorttimestring` or `.tolongtimestring` depending on the format that you are looking for.